# can Hadoop works with something else but eclips (java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, k-means

can Hadoop works with something else but eclipse (java) ? 
I run Hadoop at my laptop and deal with it using K-means java code (eclipse) but it stop running can I use something else to solve the problem ?

Comment: The IDE is irrelevant.

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: It means it doesn't matter if you're using Eclipse or not; Eclipse is an IDE, Hadoop is a Java library, you can run your code from the command line, a different IDE, etc. It might be a good idea to figure out why it "stopped running", though.

Comment: thank you ,, I dnt know why it stop running ,, no errors there and no any msg appears ,, 
so I can't use C or C# ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Hadoop is written in Java, you run it under Java. Do you mean you want C or C# jobs? To control Hadoop with C/C#? Seems a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

```
can Hadoop works with something else but eclipse (java) ?
```

Yes it can. Eclipse is just an IDE(integrated development environment)  to write your program. It has nothing to do with hadoop Map Reduce programming. You can even use NetBeans or try to use a different version, as the version of eclipse you are using may not be compatible with hadoop.